# RDLC reports are not respecting my page height option

Tags: reporting, rdlc

I am passing in this DeviceInfo to the report:

```xml
<DeviceInfo>
  <OutputFormat>Word</OutputFormat>
  <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>
  <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>
  <MarginTop>1in</MarginTop>
  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>
  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>
  <MarginBottom>1in</MarginBottom>
</DeviceInfo>
```

However when the report renders (as Word or PDF), the page size is 11 by 11 inches, rather than 11 by 8.5 (landscape). Why is this? How can I get the report to render with the proper size?

Here is where I render the report:

```cs
byte[] bytes = Report.Render( // Report is an instance of the Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport class
    reportType,
    deviceInfo, // this contains the XML above
    out mimeType,
    out encoding,
    out fileNameExtension,
    out streams,
    out warnings);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Report builder or Visual Studio you have also to set the Layout of the Report to `Landscape` so it will know how to render[image: Landscape Property]

Comment: Hmm, I'm not using a report builder or Visual Studio to define the report; rather I'm using C# code to generate the report. Do you know where this would be set?

Comment: you are using C# code to generate the `*.rdlc` files?

you could try this:

`System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
ps.Landscape = true;
ps.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1170);
ps.PaperSize.RawKind = (int)System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4;
reportViewer.SetPageSettings(ps);`

I never tried that, give it a try :)

Comment: I'm not using a `ReportViewer`; the report is generated as HTML, PDF, Word, or Excel using the `Report.Render` call above.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, how you create the definition file of the `rdlc` file ? - if you do not use an ReportViewer try at least to use in the code just to export the report and not to place it in the GUI

Comment: The RDLC is generated using a variety of custom classes which output various RDLC XML elements.

Comment: Well then you have to modify the xml definition I guess.. I'm not sure about the xml structure of the rdlc definition itself - you need to google that if that is possible. Good Luck

Comment: Try This link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455090/printing-landscape-portrait-in-rdlc-without-preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201618/discussion-between-flamur-muji-and-ekolis).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the report page size was not being initialized properly, so I did so:

```cs
var page = report.Page;

page.LeftMargin = LeftMargin;
page.RightMargin = RightMargin;

page.TopMargin = TopMargin;
page.BottomMargin = BottomMargin;

// I added these next two lines
page.PageWidth = PageWidth;
page.PageHeight = PageHeight;
```